# Static Resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inversion-of-control

I have a class in WPF that is referenced in XAML as a view control:

```
<ctrl:MyController x:Key="Controller"/>
```

I can now access this as a static resource and all is fine:

```
Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Controller}, Path=HistoryFutureRetrieveLeft,
Mode=OneTime}">
```

However I now need to create the controller using an IOC container. I can do this with the following code:

```
Resources.Add("Controller", App.IocContainer.Resolve<MyController>());
```

But I have to remove the line from the XAML,:

```
<ctrl:MyController x:Key="Controller"/>
```

This isn't a problem at run time but this does cause a problem when trying to edit the XAML because all the bindings now say the "Resource Controller is not found". Is there any way to allow the IOC container to create the controller at run time but to define the controller in the XAML file purely for the VS designer?

Comment: Leave the `Controller` declaration in the XAML when you're working in the designer and just comment it out when you run?

Answer (score 0):

You can leave statically defined controller in XAML to satisfy designer, and replace it in runtime with a proper one from container.

**Update**: 
Could you use DataContext instead of modifying resources?

```
this.DataContext = App.IocContainer.Resolve<MyController>()
```

Then you can specify data context type in XAML (d:DataContext) to make designer happy and have intellisense.

Comment: If I try to do this it complains that the controller does not have a public parameterless constructor.